# How to export a SP list with a view called "MyView" with PnPPowershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Hi I have this code which work great. But now I want to export the list in a certain view I have created. How can I do that.

```
$hashTable = @()
$items = Get-PnpListItem -List "MySchedule"
foreach($item in $items)
{
$HashTable += New-Object psobject -Property @{ 
'Datum'=$item.FieldValues.Datum.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
'00:00 - 07:59'=$item.FieldValues._x0030_0_x003a_00_x0020__x002d__;
'08:00 - 16:59'=$item.FieldValues._x0030_8_x003a_00_x0020__x002d__;
'17:00 - 23:59'=$item.FieldValues._x0031_7_x003a_00_x0020__x002d__;  
'Opmerkingen'=$item.FieldValues.Opmerkingen; 
  } 
} 
$hashTable | Select Datum,'00:00 - 07:59','08:00 - 16:59','17:00 - 23:59',Opmerkingen |
epcsv "c:\temp\myschedule.csv" -NoT
```

Gr, P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [blog](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/how-to-export-a-sharepoint-list-view-to-excel-automatically-using-powershell/).  It has a step-by-step walk-through.

You will be using the /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll RPC endpoint.  See MSFT documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms478653(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: I don't understand. I use the PnPowershell module not the Microsoft module, This is what I need in PnpPowershell: $library = $web.Lists["Test"]
$view = $library.Views["All Documents"]

Comment: you can substitute the PNP equivalents for the SharePoint on-prem cmdlets.  $library = $web.Lists["Test"] $view = $library.Views["All Documents"] are just objects.  you can retrieve the objects like so:  $library = Get-PnPList -identity "lists/test";  there is no OOB way other than adapting the code in the blog.